# Url returning base64 endcoded string not working inside image tag?

Tags: image, aws-lambda, base64, aws-api-gateway

I have a simple lambda function which returns a base64 encoded image string
`https://mfaly878w7.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/test` . The URL returns the string when I put it directly in the browser and the string is correct and its rendering image if I put it in the html image tag.

But if I use the URL directly in the html image tag`<img src="https://mfaly878w7.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/test">` I am not getting the image.
So is there a way I can use the url directly in image tag?

Answer (score 0):

In the string the you lambda reutrn add `data:image/png;base64,` prefix

```js
var b64Response = "�PNG....";
return `data:image/png;base64,${b64Response}`;
```